# Syntax to bind a ToggleButton IsChecked property to a RichTextBox's attached behavior

Tags: wpf, xaml, attachedbehaviors

WPF.

I have a behavior:

```
public class RichTextBehavior : Behavior<RichTextBox>
    {
         public bool TextBold
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(TextBoldProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextBoldProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for TextBold.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextBoldProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TextBold", typeof(bool), typeof(RichTextBehavior),
             new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnTextBoldChanged));

        private static void OnTextBoldChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var behavior = d as RichTextBehavior;
            TextRange tr = new TextRange(behavior.AssociatedObject.Selection.Start, behavior.AssociatedObject.Selection.End);
            if (tr == null)
                return;

            // This Works, but also adds keyboard commands.
            //EditingCommands.ToggleBold.Execute(null, behavior.AssociatedObject);

            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
                //TextSelection ts = richTextBox.Selection;

                tr.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);
            else
                tr.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Normal);

        }
```

That is attached to a RichTextBox as:

```
 <RichTextBox x:Name="RichTextControl" ...
                            >
                        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <b:RichTextBehavior TextFont="{Binding ElementName=Fonttype, Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

                    </RichTextBox>
```

I would like to bind a ToggleButton IsChecked property to the 'TextBold' property of the behavior (in XAML), ***something*** like:

```
<ToggleButton Name="ToggleBold"  Command="EditingCommands.ToggleBold" 
       CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=RichTextControl}"
        IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=RichTextControl, Path=(TextBold), Mode=TwoWay}"
        .......................................           
 </ToggleButton>
```

How is this done? What is the syntax?
Any idea is much appreciated. 
TIA

Edit:

I believe this should work, but it doesn't. In action, depressing the Bold Toggle button DOES change the typed text on the RichTextBox (as it should with the EditingCommands.ToggleBold), but as before, selecting text already in the RichTextBox does NOT change the state of the ToggleBold when bound to the IsChecked property.

I believe this should have worked ( but does not seem to respect the IsChecked Binding):

```
 <ToggleButton Name="ToggleBold"  
Command="EditingCommands.ToggleBold" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=RichTextControl}"
    IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=RichTextControl, 
 Path=(b:RichTextBehavior.TextBold), Mode=TwoWay}"........
```

I might add, for some reason, every key press in the RichTextBox seems to call SelectionChanged in the behavior twice, (not once as I would expect), and the second call does not seem to have the already-set value of the first call. Weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle `SelectionChanged` event in the Behavior:

```
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += RichTextBoxSelectionChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= RichTextBoxSelectionChanged;
    }
```

and set `TextBold` propertly, by using `GetPropertyValue`:

```
    void RichTextBoxSelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextRange tr = new TextRange(AssociatedObject.Selection.Start, AssociatedObject.Selection.End);
        if (tr == null)
            return;
        FontWeight g = (FontWeight)tr.GetPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty); 
        TextBold = g == FontWeights.Bold;
    }
```

Use two way binding (I use `CheckBox`):

```
<StackPanel> 
    <RichTextBox x:Name="RichTextControl" >
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <local:RichTextBehavior TextBold="{Binding ElementName=fonttype, Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors> 
    </RichTextBox>
    <CheckBox x:Name="fonttype"  Content="Is Bold"   /> 
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I did not consider using a checkbox. Is there an issue with ToggleButton? Please see my Edit. Thanks.

Comment: Works with ToggleButton too. Did you have problem using it?

Comment: I have much to learn. Apparently, using IsChecked from the ToggleButton/CheckBox was calling SelectionChanged again and/or the way I specified the binding from the ToggleButton was perhaps referencing a different object then the behavior on the RichTextBox (I don't know?). In either case, removing the IsChecked binding from the ToggleButton (as you did) and using your solution works perfectly. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
     <RichTextBox x:Name="RichTextControl">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <b:RichTextBehavior TextBold="{Binding ElementName=toggleBold,Path=IsChecked}" />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </RichTextBox>
    <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleBold" Content="Bold" />
```

Comment: Actually looking for it the other way. i.e., the target is the ToggleButton. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your mean, is this what you want: adding Mode=OneWayToSource to the binding?

Comment: Tried it. No luck.

Comment: I now realize this was actually the correct answer as well, I was just too tired to recognize it.